# Get database generated ID after persist in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to retrieve the ID that a database generates after a `persist()`. My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableName")
public class TableNameClass {

    @Id
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
private int ID;

    ...
}
```

However, when executing the next piece of code, the entity is saved in the DB but the result of the `System.out.println` is 0:

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
TableNameClass tnc = new TableNameClass();
tnc.setName("SessionTest4");
Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
s.save(tnc);
t.commit();
System.out.println(tnc.getID());
s.close();
```

Could anybody help me, please?

PD: I don't care about using Session or EntityManager, so a solution on any one of them will be fine.

**EDIT:**

I've tried adding a `flush()` after the `save()` method, but still not working:

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
AlertType at = new AlertType();
at.setName("SessionTest4");
Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
s.save(at);
s.flush();
t.commit();        
System.out.println(at.getID());
s.close();
```

I've also tried adding the `flush()` function after the `commit()`, however an Exception is thrown saying that there is no Transaction active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a solution:

**ENTITY**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableName")
public class TableNameClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private int ID;

    ...
}
```

**CREATE FUNCTION**

```
TableNameClass tnc = new TableNameClass();
tnc.setName("Solution");
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
Integer myID = (Integer)s.save(tnc);
t.commit();
s.close();
System.out.println(myID);
```

As you can see, I've changed the `@Generated` annotation for `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. I don't know if both of them represent the same, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a

```
em.flush();
```

to force the entity manager to synchronize the data.  Then `at.getID()` will return the value.

Comment: Still not working. I've updated the question with the changes I've done. Any idea? I'm using Hibernate 5.2.4 Final

Comment: The commit closed the transaction and isn't needed if you are using CMP. Take that out and see if it works.

Comment: Still not working. I've removed the persist() but still returning 0. I've also tried by saving the entity without a Transaction, following this tutorial [link](http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example) and enabling the auto commit property, but I think this is not working anymore on the newest version of Hibernate.